# Is project-tango still usable for ar development?

Tags: google-project-tango

I I am doing a small demo project on indoor navigation recently. I have chosen project tango whit Unity and I just bought the lenovo Phab 2 Pro. However I just found that tango has been abandoned by google...

So I want to know should I countinue to use tango if I just want to develope a AR indoor navigation project,not considering business?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in your situation too. Just bought ZenFone AR. I'm going to learn AR using this device and project tango. Hoping the depth cameras will rule the AR/MR world again :)))